# In Blend S Episode 7, why were strawberries sold out in every market?

Tags: blend-s

This made Maika completely lose her temper, and she got completely out of control.  Why were they sold out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I watched this particular scene again and *it was never elaborated as to why*. The only reasons I could see of a fruit going out of stock are:

1. **Unusually high demand from the public**, which could be for any reason.
2. **It is not in season**. According to [this site](https://www.japan-talk.com/jt/new/ichigo), Japanese strawberries are in season for half the year, from December to June. It could be that this particular episode was set after these months or when the strawberry season was ending. In which case, the supply of strawberries would, understandably, be low.

Comment: Why are Japanese strawberries season so limited?

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya Well, it's not just strawberry that are seasonal. But I'm not a biology or agriculture major so I'm not sure if I can provide a sufficient answer, sorry. However, I think you can ask this in the Biology Stackexchange site, but double-check their site policies to make sure it is on-topic. I'm sure they can provide better answers there than I can.